# uninitialized constant Mime::CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, redmine

I am trying to start redmine and I got this error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Mime::CSV
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/20-mime_types.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Version of rails: Rails 6.0.3.2. I have tried to add require 'mime' to the 20-mime_types.rb file, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the `Redmine` version you've used, but even latest `Redmine` for now (*4.1.7*) expects `Rails 5.1`

So please take into account [official requirements](https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall)